# The loop for does not to print when using a variable in sqlite python

Tags: python, sqlite

The cursor execute SELECT is matched with the variable "s" but
The loop "for" does not work (nothing is printed) using "s", However, it works with the cursor execute SELECT directly. What is the problem? Isn't "s" the same object than cursor execute SELECT?

The programming routine is the following:

```
>>>import sqlite3
>>>con=sqlite3.connect('prueba.db')
>>>cur=con.cursor()
>>>cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE tabla1(ExtremoA text,ExtremoZ text,PotenciaRxA real,PotenciaTxA real,PotenciaRxZ real,PotenciaTxZ real,SpanLossAZ real,SpanLossZA real)''')
print "Tabla1 creada exitosamente"
>>>registros=[('Quillota','San felipe',-9,4,-11,3,15,12),('San Felipe','Las Cuevas',-10,2,-12,6,16,14)]
>>>sql='''INSERT INTO tabla1(ExtremoA,ExtremoZ,PotenciaRxA,PotenciaTxA,PotenciaRxZ,PotenciaTxZ,SpanLossAZ,SpanLossZA)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'''
>>>cur.executemany(sql,registros)
>>>con.commit()
>>>print "registros creados exitosamente"
>>>s=cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM tabla1''')   
>>>todo=cur.fetchall()
>>>print todo
>>>for i in s:
    print i
>>>cur.close()
>>>con.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `todo=cur.fetchall()` you've already retrieved the rows into `todo` so there's nothing left to iterate over anyway. So loop over `todo` instead of `s`... Otherwise, get rid of that line and loop over `cur`...

Comment: I've got it!some concepts are not very clear for me. That's all ok.